# each on jQuery function is not working properly

Tags: jquery, function, each

I'm trying to create a jQuery plugin to output some sample texts after the target element.

My codes like this

**jQuery function**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getVideo = function(){        
        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).wrapAll('<div class="wrap-getvideo" />')
            $wrapGetvideo = $(this).closest('.wrap-getvideo');
            $wrapGetvideo.append('<div class="title"></div>');

            $(this).on('keyup', function(){
                $wrapGetvideo.find('.title').html('Testing');
            });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

**Calling the function**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.getvideo').getVideo();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="getvideo" type="text" placeholder="Enter video URL">

<input class="getvideo" type="text" placeholder="Enter video URL">

<input class="getvideo" type="text" placeholder="Enter video URL">
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/8pbpm547/

As you can see the HTML above, I have used that plugin 3 input boxes and each should output the sample text 'Testing' next to it when keyup. But only the last one is showing.

What's wrong in my code and how can get the text output on all 3 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `var` statement, right now `$wrapGetvideo` is global, and is overwritten on each iteration, which is why it only works on the last one

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getVideo = function(){        
        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).wrapAll('<div class="wrap-getvideo" />')
            var $wrapGetvideo = $(this).closest('.wrap-getvideo');
            $wrapGetvideo.append('<div class="title"></div>');

            $(this).on('keyup', function(){
                $wrapGetvideo.find('.title').html('Testing');
            });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8pbpm547/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It works. Could you please tell me what are the differences between variables such as var abc, var $abc and $abc?

Comment: @Body - MDN probably does it better than I do -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Answer (score 2):

You are updating `$wrapGetvideo` (global variable) with `$(this).closest('.wrap-getvideo')` in jquery each and finally `$wrapGetvideo` will have your last element reference.Try this:

```
 $(this).on('keyup', function(){
   $(this).closest('.wrap-getvideo').find('.title').html('Testing');
 });
```

Instead of

```
$(this).on('keyup', function(){
      $wrapGetvideo.find('.title').html('Testing');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/8pbpm547/2/)**